# Escaping Docker attach one started from bash script

Tags: bash, docker, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm running Docker commands from a [management script](https://github.com/svenvandescheur/docker-template/blob/master/manage.sh) and one of the commands I use is attach.

Attaching works fine but I can't seam to leave the output either by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

My theory is that the key signals are not fetched by Docker since bash is running front of it.

Is this correct? And how do I solve this?

Comment: At the end indeed an eval is executed. Is there some way to preserve the TTY using eval?

Comment: I was mistaken actually. I thought that was the case, but testing it here proved I was wrong.

Comment: I manually ran the command and then tried docker attach. Same problem (so the script doesn't affect it). Looks like that if a command is run without the -t flag (TTY) output works but I cant quit it. If the -t flag is used it seems to work.

Comment: My `docker attach` doesn't show `-t` as an option. That was going to be my second suggestion. Glad you got it working though.

Comment: The -t is set on run, which opens up a tty "Allocate a pseudo-tty"